# Cannot implicity convert "void" to "bool"

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can anyone point to me what is wrong with the code I have? The first function is on a different aspx file than the second function.

```
    protected void btnManageUsersAddUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (clsDataLayer.SaveUser(Server.MapPath("PayrollSystem_DB.mdb"), txtManageUsersName.Text, txtManageUsersPassword.Text, ddlSecurityLevel.SelectedValue))
    {
        lblAddUserMsg.Text = "The user was successfully added";
        grdManagePersonnel.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        lblAddUserMsg.Text = "The user was not successfully added";
    }
```

The following function has originally "bool" instead of "void" but my professor told me to change it to "void" due to error of not all returns a value.

```
    public static void SaveUser(string Database, string UserName, string UserPassword, string SecurityLevel)
{

    bool recordSaved;

    try
    {
        // Create connection
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                                                   "Data Source=" + Database);
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        string strSQL;

        // Insert to tblUserLogin
        strSQL = "Insert into tblUserLogin " +
                 "(UserName, UserPassword, SecurityLevel) values ('" +
                 UserName + "', '" + UserPassword + "', '" + SecurityLevel + "')";

        // Process data
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = strSQL;

        // Add your comments here
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        // Closes the transaction when true
        conn.Close();
        recordSaved = true;


    }
            catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: What school do you go to?

Comment: DeVry. I have the book murach's ASP.NET 3.5 with C# 2008 but not much help from that book. I guess it is only for people who have a background on programming who are new to web programming.

Comment: Please do not take offense to this, but I recommend you look at this free eBook: C# for Sharp Kids (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/bb308756.aspx). Understanding the basics of the language is step 1 and then learning how to apply those concepts is crucial if you wish to become a competent developer.

Comment: As for your example code, you stated that originally you had a Boolean (bool) as the return type and then your professor suggested that you make it void, because you were not returning a value for all paths. Did you tell him that you wanted to know if the "save" worked or not and that your message to the user was predicated on success or failure of that information being saved?

Answer (score 5):

Since you have changed the method return type to type **void**, you can no longer use it in the conditional statement you have here:

```
if (clsDataLayer.SaveUser(Server.MapPath("PayrollSystem_DB.mdb"), 
    txtManageUsersName.Text, txtManageUsersPassword.Text, ddlSecurityLevel.SelectedValue))
```

...the conditional expects the expression to be reduced to a **boolean** value.

Your professor might have had a point that not all paths returned a value in a previous edition of your code. You will need to make sure that all paths return a true or false value if your method returns a boolean. For example, you could modify your code to return a boolean value again and return the following values:

```
...
return true;

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   return false;
}
...
```

Note that I have removed the "recordSaved" variable as it was unnecessary; if you are only going to use it in that one spot I would suggest returning the true/false values themselves.

Comment: +1 for a better solution than the professor's recommendation.

Comment: Somehow, VS2012 showing me a log on return cannot be followed by object expression. I was using VS2008 before but switched to VS2012 due to freezing everytime I open my file.

Comment: @tcgt584 Make sure you change your method from "public static void SaveUser" to "public static bool SaveUser"

Comment: It worked. Thank you for pointing that out. Both modifications worked. So there are multiple ways to do it and get it to work.

Comment: @tcgt584 Glad it worked. You might have to talk with your Professor about taking his/her time next time :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you changed it to return nothing but then you still expect it to return something because you're still trying to use the result:

```
if (clsDataLayer.SaveUser( ...
```

Either change that expectation (losing the ability to return valuable information to the caller), or go back to your original version and ensure all code paths return a value.

Your professor's advice is akin to:

> **You:**  My car has a flat tire.
>   **Prof:** Well, take the tire off.
>   **You:**  Er, now my car *still* won't go.

While the professor's advice to remove the flat tire has indeed fixed the immediate problem (inasmuch as your car no longer has a flat tire), it's not really an adequate solution. Changing things without understanding the *root cause <sup>(a)</sup>* of the problem frequently leads to situations like that you currently find yourself in.

Your professor should have advised you to understand *why* you were getting the error and fix *that,* rather than opting for a quick fix with ramifications elsewhere.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The root cause of this problem is not that your value returns a boolean value, it's because there's a mismatch between what the caller expects and what the callee delivers.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the flaw with the professor's recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with your professors recommendation.   Changing the return type of your method to void because all paths do not return a value is like slapping a bandage on an infected cut and expecting it to heal.

A better solution, IMO, would be to ensure that all paths **do** return a value (either true or false).

For example, in your method, change:

```
bool recordSaved;
```

to:

```
bool recordSaved = false;
```

Then, if at the end of your `try` section (before the `catch` line), add:

```
recordSaved = true;
```

Then return `recordSaved` before exiting the method:

```
return recordSaved;
```

With these changes, your method will set the `recordSaved` value to false; it only gets set to true if the record is saved.  Then you can return the value, and use the method in your `if` check.

The complete code would look something like this:

```
public static bool SaveUser(string Database, string UserName, string UserPassword, string SecurityLevel)
{

    bool recordSaved = false;

    try
    {
        // do your save
        recordSaved = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // Handle the exception (logging, etc)
    }

    return recordSaved;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, why do we need to set the bool recordSaved to false and have the return recordSaved? I used the other function in the file as a template for this.

Comment: You don't have to set it to false.  I generally do when I'm using a variable as a success/no success flag.  I set it to false at the start and then only flip it to true if whatever I was doing was successful.  It's more or less a personal preference/style choice.  Not sure what you mean by the second part of your question on the return - if the method returns a value, it has to have a return statement (at least one, but can be more if there's conditional logic involved).

Comment: So doing that is only by personal preference. Thank you. Now I have to work on the other error "FormsAuthentication" does not exist in current context.